# pasar datos onItemClickListener de in ListView cargado con JSON para mostrarlos en otro activity

Tags: android, json, android-studio, listview

Necesito controlar la pulsación sobre el Listview personalizado para que realice una operación dependiendo el que se pulsa. Ya tengo el OnItemClickListener.

Pero, como puedo pasar los datos contenidos en el Item hacia otra Activity

Les dejo el código principal

```
public class Noticias extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Product> arrayList;
    ListView lv;
    ProgressDialog pdialog = null;
    Context context = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_noticias);
        android:setTitle("Noticias");

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        context = this;


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Buscando Noticias...", true);
                new ReadJSON().execute("http://xxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx.php");
            }
        });

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click en la posición "  + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return readURL(params[0]);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
            pdialog.dismiss();
            try {
                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(content);
                for(int i =0;i<jsonarray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject productObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    arrayList.add(new Product(
                            productObject.getString("nombre"),
                            productObject.getString("contenido"),
                            productObject.getString("extra1")

                    ));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_list_layout, arrayList
            );
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }


    private static String readURL(String theUrl) {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            // create a url object
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);
            // create a urlconnection object
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            // wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(line + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content.toString();
    }
}
```

Llevo varios días buscando y solo encuentro información con Arrays creados localmente

Este es el codigo de la nueva actividad en donde recibo los datos del Item

```
public class Noticia extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvname,tvcontenido;
    ImageView imgview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_noticia);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String nombre = intent.getStringExtra("nombre");
        String contenido = intent.getStringExtra("contenido");
        String extra1 = intent.getStringExtra("extra1");

        tvname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvname);
        tvcontenido = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcontenido);
        imgview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview);

        tvname.setText(nombre);
        tvcontenido.setText(contenido);
        imgview.setImageURI(Uri.parse(extra1));
    }
}
```

Pero solo me muestra los campos con texto... la Imagen no la muestra

Comment: **esto ya fue respodido en varias ocasiones en este sitio**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para enviar los parámetros a una nueva actividad, primero deberás obtener el objeto del ArrayList ya que onItemClick sólo nos devuelve la posición y finalmente enviar la información en el Intent.

Te dejo el ejemplo hecho para el código que has mostrado:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        Product selectedProduct = arrayList.get(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NuevaActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("nombre", selectedProduct.getName());
        intent.putExtra("contenido", selectedProduct.getContent());
        intent.putExtra("extra1", selectedProduct.getExtra());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Ten en cuenta que las funciones getName(), getContent(), getExtra() deben existir en la clase Producto y devolver el string correspondiente.

Una vez enviados los datos en el Intent, deberás obtenerlos en NuevaActivity de esta forma:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nueva_activity);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String nombre = intent.getStringExtra("nombre");
    String contenido = intent.getStringExtra("contenido");
    String extra = intent.getStringExtra("extra1");

    ... Resto de codigo de tu actividad, como los setText correpondientes etc...
}
```

Comment: Ya logre imprimir el campo nombre y el campo contenido. Pero la imagen no se muestra. Te comento que en el String extra = intent.getStringExtra("extra"); va una Imagen

Comment: te anexe el codigo de la nueva actividad

Comment: @Sharly Infinitywars me confundí en mi mensaje es String extra = intent.getStringExtra("extra1"); en lugar de String extra = intent.getStringExtra("extra"); ya lo he corregido en mi respuesta

Comment: @SharlyInfinitywars para cargar una imagen desde URL en un ImageView te recomiendo hacer uso de una librería como [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) por ejemplo

Comment: estoy utilizando la libreria picasso...

Comment: @SharlyInfinitywars picasso serviría tambien, usa esta línea en lugar del setImageURI: Picasso.with(this).load(extra1).into(imgview);

Comment: muchas gracias... si me funciono.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Deberías utilizar un [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html?hl=es-419) para pasar la información a la nueva Actividad.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, tuNuevaActivdad.class);
```

Y asignarle la información que quieres pasar con el método `putExtra`:

```
intent.putExtra("loquequieras", "tuValor");
```

Por último, lanzar el Intent:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Dentro de tu `listView` quedaría:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, tuNuevaActivdad.class);
            intent.putExtra("loquequieras", "tuValor");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Y después para recuperar los datos desde tu Actividad `tuNuevaActividad` deberías de recoger el intent mediante el método `getIntent` y la información mediante el método `getStringExtra` ya que en este caso hemos pasado un `String`.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String tuValor = intent.getStringExtra("loquequieras"); //Recuperas el String "tuValor"
```

**Muy importante:**

- El string significativo, en este caso, `loquequieras` debe ser igual tanto a la hora de asignar los datos como para recuperarlos. Le puedes poner el `String` identificativo que quieras.
- No es obligatorio que como segundo parámetro le pases un `String`. Le puedes pasar `int`, `Char`, `Serializable`, etc... Puedes ver todos los tipos de dato que le puedes pasar [aquí](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html?hl=es-419#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). También tienes que tener en cuenta que para recuperar los datos también cambiará el método a `getIntExtra`, `getCharExtra`, `getSerializableExtra`, etc. según el tipo de dato que le hayas pasado.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deseas es enviar variables entre Activities, esto se realiza mediante un Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("VARIABLE1", variable);
intent.putExtra("VARIABLE2", otravariable);
startActivity(intent);
```

En la Activity que recibe estos valores, los puedes obtener mediante el [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html):

```
 Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
 String variable_recibida1 = b.getString("VARIABLE1");
 String variable_rcibida2 = b.getString("VARIABLE2");
```

Para ejecutar el intent desde tu Activity, pro medio de un botón,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Envía datos!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

simplemente agrega un listener al botón para que realize el intent:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("VARIABLE1", variable);
    intent.putExtra("VARIABLE2", otravariable);
    startActivity(intent);

    }

});
```