# Cambiar de pantalla Adaptador

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo la siguiente parte de mi programa:

```
  // Si clickem a sobre de qualsevol d'ells...
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> pariente, View view, int posicion, long id) {
            Lista_entrada elegido = (Lista_entrada) pariente.getItemAtPosition(posicion);

            CharSequence texto = "Seleccionado: " + elegido.get_textoDebajo();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, texto, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

He conseguido que al clickar encima de un texto me muestre un toast, pero no consigo cambiar de actividad.. Es decir necesito irme a otra pantalla por ejemplo Pantalla.class.

Podéis ayudarme?

Gracias!

Comment: debes de usar Intent. Aquí un ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36133/pasar-datos-onitemclicklistener-de-in-listview-cargado-con-json-para-mostrarlos

Comment: sé que necesito una actividad y lo he probado pero no hay forma T_T